# "the aggregation node for control 'sap.ui.table.Table' is incorrect" error

Tags: sapui5

I have just started with learning `UI5` coding and I am not a pro in it.

I am trying to add a combo box in my search field to enhance the search option in my application, so I am using the table tag but whenever I try to insert the code:

```xml
<t:Table id="idoclist" selectionMode="MultiToggle" rows="{idoc_list_msg>/results}"
    visibleRowCount="12"  cellClick="onPress" sort="sortDeliveryDate"
    enableCellFilter="{ui>/cellFilterOn}" ariaLabelledBy="title">
    <t:headerToolbar>
    <t:toolbar>
        <Title text="IDOC Data" level="H1"/>
            <t:ToolbarSpacer/>
            <ComboBox id="filtercombo">
                <core:Item key="Trkorr" text="IDOC Number"/>
                <core:Item key="TrType" text="Created ON"/>
                <core:Item key="As4text" text="IDOC Type"/>
                <core:Item key="" text=""/>
            </ComboBox>
            <SearchField width="50%" search="onFilter" placeholder="Filter"/>
    </t:toolbar>
    </t:headerToolbar>
    <!-- ... -->
```

I get error saying:

> the aggregation node for control 'sap.ui.table.Table' is incorrect.

Can somebody please help me if I am missing on to something before this.

Comment: Always check the [API reference: `sap.ui.table.Table`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.table.Table#aggregations). `<headerToolbar>` is not a valid aggregation for the Grid Table. And `<toolbar>` is deprecated. The view definition is also syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

The `headerToolbar` is not a valid aggregation for `sap.ui.table.Table`. This means that you cannot use `headerToolbar` inside `Table` directly. Your next option would be to use the `toolbar` aggregation. But this has been deprecated since version 1.38 (refer to [this](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.Table) document to know more about `sap.ui.table.Table`).

So you can use the extension aggregation to include your toolbar. I have modified your table with `sap.m.Toolbar`.

```xml
<t:Table id="idoclist" selectionMode="MultiToggle" rows="{idoc_list_msg>/results}"
    visibleRowCount="12" cellClick="onPress" sort="sortDeliveryDate"
    enableCellFilter="{ui>/cellFilterOn}" ariaLabelledBy="title">
    <t:extension>
        <Toolbar>
            <Title text="IDOC Data" level="H1"/>
            <ToolbarSpacer/>
            <ComboBox id="filtercombo">
                <core:Item key="Trkorr" text="IDOC Number"/>
                <core:Item key="TrType" text="Created ON"/>
                <core:Item key="As4text" text="IDOC Type"/>
                <core:Item key="" text=""/>
            </ComboBox>
            <SearchField width="50%" search="onFilter" placeholder="Filter"/>
        </Toolbar>
    </t:extension>
</t:Table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the [content aggregation](https://webidecp-accccc64c.dispatcher.hana.ondemand.com/ui5templates/sdk/#/api/sap.m.Toolbar/aggregations) on your toolbar. It should look like this:

```xml
<t:Table id="idoclist" selectionMode="MultiToggle" 
    rows="{idoc_list_msg>/results}" visibleRowCount="12" cellClick="onPress"
    sort="sortDeliveryDate" enableCellFilter="{ui>/cellFilterOn}" ariaLabelledBy="title">
        <t:headerToolbar>
            <t:toolbar>
                <content>
                    <Title text="IDOC Data" level="H1"/>
                    <t:ToolbarSpacer/>
                    <ComboBox id="filtercombo">
                        <core:Item key="Trkorr" text="IDOC Number"/>
                        <core:Item key="TrType" text="Created ON"/>
                        <core:Item key="As4text" text="IDOC Type"/>
                        <core:Item key="" text=""/>
                    </ComboBox>
                    <SearchField width="50%" search="onFilter" placeholder="Filter"/>
                </content>
            </t:toolbar>
         </t:headerToolbar>
         <!-- ... -->
```

The [sap.ui.core.Toolbar](https://webidecp-accccc64c.dispatcher.hana.ondemand.com/ui5templates/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.core.Toolbar) aggregation is now deprecated as of version 1.38 for [sap.ui.table.Table](https://webidecp-accccc64c.dispatcher.hana.ondemand.com/ui5templates/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.table.Table) so I would recommend using [sap.m.Table](https://webidecp-accccc64c.dispatcher.hana.ondemand.com/ui5templates/sdk/#/api/sap.m.Table) on your view to look something like this:

```xml
<Table id="_yourTable">
       <headerToolbar>
          <Toolbar>
             <content>
                <Label text="Toolbar Label"></Label>
             </content>
          </Toolbar>
       </headerToolbar>
       <!-- ... -->
```

Comment: There's more going on with this... assuming `t:` points to `sap.ui.table`, the toolbar control is `sap.ui.table.toolbar` which does not exist. there's no `headerToolbar` aggregation on `sap.ui.table.Table` but there is on `sap.m.Table`.

Comment: @Jorg thought the same, just edited my answer. I think sap.m.Table should be used here.

Comment: Or the `extension` aggregation on `sap.ui.table.Table` I guess... I'd suggest `sap.m.Table` too.